# If statement inside for loop only works for first item

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The below for loop works fine for all elements in the array (args is an array) but the if statement inside the loop only works for the first element.

```
for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        let asl = args[i].split('--')[1].split('="')[0];
        let asl2 = args[i].split('--')[1];
        console.log(i)
        if (asl == 'vote' || asl == 'maxusers') {
          let flag = asl2.split('="')[0];
          let value = asl2.split('="')[1].split('"')[0];
          if (flag == 'vote') {
            votet = value;
          } else if (flag == 'maxusers') {
            maxu = value;
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I guess that `asl == 'vote' || asl == 'maxusers'` is `true` only for the first item

Comment: Can you share the value of args here so we can answer?

Comment: --maxusers="10" is args[0] and --value="20" is args[1]

Comment: seems like `asl` and `flag` would always be the same thing - very much overcomplicated code to be honest - anyway, with those arguments, the code works as it should ... maxu === 10 ... since the seconds argument is `--value` it doesn't match either `vote` or `maxusers` ... therefore `votet` won't be assigned

Comment: yeah was editing smt earlier but shouldn't it work tho ?

Comment: yes, `votet` won't be assigned at all since there's no `--vote="???"` and `maxu` will be `10`